# External Storage on android

Tags: android, storage

I have an application that creates a log file on external device and passes the log file path to the underlying ndk library for logging.

I am using Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) before creating the log file to check whether the external storage is available for logging. My question is what will happen if the user mounts the device onto a computer after creating the log file?

Would my application still be able to access the log file?

Comment: No, it won't. That means you need to gracefully handle any IO errors that may result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Drake said in his comment, when you attach the phone to a computer and choose to mount it as a drive the external storage will become unavailable to the phone. I guess you read it but it's described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).